# pgfplots, bar graph, axis distance

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I have a following chart, and I am trying to decrease the distance between the x-axis ticks FCC and Beta pi. Any suggestions on how to reduce this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
%legend columns=-1,
legend cell align=left,
every axis plot post/.style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
ybar=2pt,
bar width=10pt,
x=5cm,
y=4.5cm,
ymin=0,
axis on top,
%ymax=12,
xtick=data,
%xlabel=Cores,
ylabel=Peak Energy (E),
enlarge x limits=0.2,
%enlarge y limits={abs=0.5},
symbolic x coords={FCC,Beta pi},
%restrict y to domain*=0:11, % Cut values off at 14
visualization depends on=rawy\as\rawy, % Save the unclipped values
after end axis/.code={ % Draw line indicating break
\draw [ultra thick, white] (rel axis cs:0,1.05) -- (rel axis cs:1,1.05);
    },
nodes near coords={\scriptsize{\pgfmathprintnumber{\rawy}}
    },
axis lines*=left,
clip=false,
area legend
%legend style={at={(0.6,0.8)},anchor=west}
]
\addplot[fill=red!40] coordinates {(FCC,0.7) (Beta pi,0.66) };
\addplot[fill=yellow!40] coordinates {(FCC,1) (Beta pi,0.81) };
\addplot[fill=blue!40] coordinates {(FCC,0.6) (Beta pi,0.74)};
\addplot[fill=green!40] coordinates {(FCC,0.5) (Beta pi,0.7)};
\legend{x264,bodytrack,swaptions,blacksholes};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Unreasonably big empty white space]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are different ways of getting rid of that big empty space:

- Decrease the overall width of the plot, moving the groups of bars closer together. You can do this by specifying a unit vector for the x axis. If you add more data, the plot will grow automatically.
- Keep the overall width of the plot, but move the groups of bars closer together. You can do this by setting a larger `enlarge x limits` value. You can set this value in terms of axis units using `abs=1` if you have `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or newer in your preamble.
- Increase the width of the bars, which will fill the empty space between the groups of bars. You can do this using the `bar width` key. Note that you will also have to increase the `enlarge x limits` value, and you might want to remove the space within the groups of bars by setting `ybar=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}


\begin{document}
\parbox{14cm}{
\pgfmathsetseed{2}
{\Large \texttt{ybar}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    xtick=data
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\

{\Large \texttt{ybar, x=1cm, enlarge x limits=\{abs=0.5cm\}}}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    xtick=data,
    x=1cm,
    enlarge x limits={abs=0.5cm}
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\

{\Large \texttt{ybar, enlarge x limits=\{abs=1\}}}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ymin=0,
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    xtick=data,
    enlarge x limits={abs=1}
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}\\

{\Large \texttt{ybar=0pt, bar width=0.45, enlarge x limits=\{abs=0.5\}}}
\pgfmathsetseed{2}

\pgfmathsetseed{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar=0pt,
    ymin=0,
    samples=2,
    domain=1:2,
    xtick=data,
    bar width=0.45,
    enlarge x limits={abs=0.5}
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```