# How to supress extra x ticks and make two data series in barchart closer to each other?

Tags: bar-chart

[image]hello!
I want to have x ticks only on x-axis points 0 and 20. I tried doing it using symbolic coordinates but it did not work out. I also want distance between two data series to be 1.5 cm. How do I do that? Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} [
ybar,
ybar=0.5pt,
bar width= 0.3cm,
enlargelimits=0.15,
legend style={draw=none, font=\tiny},legend pos=outer north east,
legend image code/.code={
\draw[##1,/tikz/.cd,yshift=-0.25em]
    (0cm,0cm) rectangle (3pt,0.8em);},
ylabel style={align=center}, ylabel=Abs(450 nm),font=\bfseries,
xlabel style={align=center}, xlabel=H2O2 treatment (nm),
enlarge y limits=0.0000008, upper, 
x tick=\empty,
x corrdinates={0, 20},
extra x ticks={0, 20},
extra x tick labels={{0},{20}},
ticklabel style={font=\large, circle, fill=white, inner sep=2pt,outer sep=1pt},
x=0.5cm,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
axis line style={-},
x tick label style={rotate=vertical},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.6,
tick style={line width=1.25pt, line cap=round, tick align=outside}
]
\addlegendentry {WT}
\addplot + [color=black, fill=green!60,error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {(0,0.521) +-(0.023, 0.023)
};
\addlegendentry {dKO}
\addplot +[color=black, fill=blue!60, error bars/.cd,y dir=both,y explicit]
coordinates {(0,0.292) +-(0.043, 0.043)
};
\addlegendentry {WT T}
\addplot + [color=black, fill=green!30, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {(20, 0.125) +-(0.004, 0.004)
};
\addlegendentry{dKO T}
\addplot + [color=black, fill=blue!30, error bars/.cd, y dir=both, y explicit]
coordinates {(20, 0.241) +-(0.004, 0.004)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
[![enter image description here][1]][1]\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your MWE contains several issues, some are obvious typos ( e.g. `x corrdinates={0, 20}`) and a bunch of (partially unknown) errors, I'm to lazy to track in detail...

concerning your first question: use `xtick={0,20},` instead of `x tick=\empty`, `x coordinates={0, 20}`, `extra x ticks={0, 20}`, `extra x tick labels={{0},{20}},` to achive 0 and 20 as only xticks

for the second part refer to this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/147978/90444

and play around with the parameters `x=0.10cm` and `enlarge x limits = {abs=1.5cm}`.

Result looks like:
[image]